# How do I set my toggle to off with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, menu, navigation, sidebar

*Trying to avoid jQuery--*
I have a nav on my website that switches between a header and side-bar when the window is resized.  I have some problems when I toggle the sidebar and then resize the page. 
If I toggle the side-bar and resize the page, I have 2 problems:

1. If I toggle the side bar and expand the page, the side-bar space stays toggled with no way to collapse it.
2. The side-bar's content opacity will change to 0 unless I first collapse the side-bar, expand the page to a header, and then bring back to the side-bar state.

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle('active');
  document.getElementById("wrapper").classList.toggle('active');
}

var width = document.body.clientWidth;

function headerResize() {
  width = document.body.clientWidth;
  console.log("Width: " + width);

  if (width > 783) {
    document.getElementById("Header-to-Hamburger-slot").innerHTML = document.getElementById("java-header").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("java-footer-slot").innerHTML = document.getElementById("java-footer").innerHTML;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Header-to-Hamburger-slot").innerHTML = document.getElementById("java-hamburger").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("java-sidebar-slot").innerHTML = document.getElementById("java-sidebar").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("java-footer-slot").innerHTML = document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML;
  }
}

headerResize();

window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {

  headerResize();

})
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

#wrapper.active {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  right: 260px;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

#sidebar.active {
  right: 0px;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Please read this information, Carefully :-https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that the resizing the page would auto-toggle the side-bar content off, but it wouldn't toggle my page wrapper back to its original position.

I just had to add

```
function autoCollapse() {
    if (document.getElementById("wrapper").classList.contains("active")) {
        document.getElementById("wrapper").classList.toggle('active');
    }
}
```

And then place it inside my event listener